# Correctly formulate a constraint in Gurobi Python

Tags: python, gurobi, operations-research

I am using a python IDE with gurobi to model and solve a problem for an assignment. The problem, although not stated seems to be an OVRP(Open Vehicle Routing Problem)(with some extra constraints). The code i have right now is:

```
from itertools import combinations
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

def find_length(list):
    length = 0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        length += distances[list[i][0]][list[i][1]]
    return length


def find_tours(list):
    tours = []
    for start in list:
        this_tour = []
        begin = start[0]
        end = start[1]
        if begin == 0:

            this_tour.append(start)
            current = start
            while next_route_exists(current, list):
                current = find_next_route(current, list)
                this_tour.append(current)

            tours.append(this_tour)
    return tours


def find_next_route(current_route, list):
    end = current_route[1]
    for tuple in list:
        if tuple[0] == end:
            list.remove(tuple)
            return tuple


def next_route_exists(current_route, list):
    end = current_route[1]
    for tuple in list:
        if tuple[0] == end:
            return True
    return False


def subtourelim(model, where):
    if where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL:
        # make a list of edges selected in the solution
        vals = model.cbGetSolution(model._vars)
        selected = gp.tuplelist((i, j) for i, j in model._vars.keys() if vals[i, j] > 0.5)

        tours = find_tours(selected)
        for tour in tours:
            if find_length(tour) > 400:
                # add subtour elimination constr. for every pair of cities in tour
                model.cbLazy(gp.quicksum(distances[i][j] for i, j in tour) <= 400)


# Distances between cities

distances = [[0, 180, 240, 85, 285, 205, 235, 255, 155, 120, 230, 340, 220, 160, 240],  # Α
             [0, 0, 255, 150, 125, 100, 175, 235, 25, 65, 95, 210, 55, 135, 215],  # Β1
             [0, 0, 0, 160, 235, 160, 105, 45, 245, 255, 195, 225, 310, 115, 50],  # Β2
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 215, 125, 150, 170, 130, 110, 160, 260, 200, 75, 150],  # Β3
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 90, 130, 195, 150, 190, 50, 85, 155, 155, 185],  # Β4
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70, 135, 110, 135, 40, 135, 155, 65, 120],  # Β5
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70, 175, 200, 95, 125, 225, 70, 55],  # Β6
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 235, 250, 165, 180, 290, 110, 20],  # Β7
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 110, 225, 70, 130, 215],  # Β8
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 145, 265, 100, 135, 230],  # Β9
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 115, 135, 105, 150],  # Β10
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 185, 175],  # Β11
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 190, 270],  # Β12
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 90],  # Β13
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]  # B14

n = 15
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j > i:
            distances[j][i] = distances[i][j]

dist = {(i, j): distances[i][j] for i in range(n) for j in range(n)}
m = gp.Model()

vars = m.addVars(dist.keys(), obj=dist, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='route')

m.addConstrs(vars.sum(i, '*') <= 1 for i in range(1, n))  # a city might be the departure
m.addConstrs(vars.sum('*', i) == 1 for i in range(1, n))  # every city must be the destination

m.addConstr(vars.sum(0, '*') >= 1, "start")  # could have more than 1 vehicles
m.addConstr(vars.sum('*', 0) == 0)  # can't go back to start
m.addConstr(vars.sum(0, '*') <= 8, "start")  # can't have more than 8 vehicle

m.addConstrs(vars[i, i] == 0 for i in range(1, n))  # can't go to  current city from current city
m.addConstrs(vars[i, j] + vars[j, i] <= 1 for i in range(1, n) for j in range(1, n) if  j != i)  # eliminate double edges between cities

route_km = vars.prod(dist)
m.addConstr(route_km <= 400 * vars.sum(0, '*'))  # total km driven




# total vehicles used

total_vehicles = vars.sum(0, '*')
m.setObjective(total_vehicles, GRB.MINIMIZE)

# optimize model

m._vars = vars
m.Params.lazyConstraints = 1
m.optimize(subtourelim)
#m.optimize()

# get edges

vals = m.getAttr('x', vars)
selected = gp.tuplelist((i, j) for i, j in vals.keys() if vals[i, j] > 0.5)
print('')
tours = find_tours(selected)

i = 0
total=0
for tour in tours:
    i += 1
    print('Tour No ' + str(i) + ':')
    print(tour)
    print('is ' + str(find_length(tour)) + ' km long')
    print('')
    total+=find_length(tour)
print('Total : ' + str(total) + ' km')
```

The problem i am having right now is that, since i am new to gurobi, i can't express a constraint i want to add properly and that leads to a wrong solution coming up. The problem is with this constraint:

```
route_km = vars.prod(dist)
m.addConstr(route_km <= 400 * vars.sum(0, '*'))  # total km driven
```

which is wrong. I wanted to add a constraint that each truck can drive up to 400 km. Once that distance is driven or can't be driven if another "city" is chosen, a new truck has to be deployed(total number of trucks is 8, as stated in the constraints). If this constraint is formulated i believe i can eliminate this lazy constraint as well:

```
tours = find_tours(selected)
for tour in tours:
    if find_length(tour) > 400:
        # add subtour elimination constr. for every pair of cities in tour
        model.cbLazy(gp.quicksum(distances[i][j] for i, j in tour) <= 400)
```

Thank you in advance for any help,

George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy constraints are best suited for models that have a relatively large number of constraints. For example, in the traditional MIP model of the traveling salesman problem, there is an exponential number of subtour elimination constraints, so it makes sense to add these as lazy constraints.

It looks like you want a capacity limit on a truck, based on the total distance driven. In HP Williams' book [Model Building in Mathematical Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118443330), the Lost baggage example is quite similar; [here is a link to a Jupiter notebook for this example on the Gurobi website](https://www.gurobi.com/resource/lost_luggage_distribution/).

Comment: Thank you very much. This example was very helpful. I was able to understand my model better and finally do what i wanted to.